# Repository pattern - Joining data from two tables

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, repository-pattern, data-transfer-objects

I'm making use of two repositories in my CommentService.

```
_commentRepository
_userRepository
```

Using the _commentRepository.GetAll() function I get a list of all my comments with the following information: [Id], [Content], [UserId].

I'm trying to create a list with all the comments and some of the matching user information obtainable by the _userRepository and store this in a DTO.

```
public ListOutput<CommentUserDto> GetCommentsWithUserInformation()
{
    var comments = _commentRepository.GetAll();

    // TODO: Add comment and user information to CommentUserDto.

    return new ListOutput<CommentUserDto>
    {
        Items = Mapper.Map<List<CommentUserDto>>(comments)
    };
}
```

How can I make this work?

Some possible ideas that I found:

1. Creating a _commentUserRepository
2. Using include to somehow join the two tables (I'm using E.F.)
3. Create a Manager in my Domain layer that takes care of combining logic.

EDIT:

Comment model:

```
public class Comment
{
    public virtual string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public virtual long UserId { get; set; } // Id of User that posted Comment (always filled in)
}
```

User model:

```
public class User {
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }  
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
}
```

CommentUserDto: // Accessible class for views

```
public class CommentUserDto {
    public string Content { get; set; } // from comment
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; } // from comment
    public string PosterName { get; set; } // from user
    public string PosterSurname { get; set; } // from user
}
```

Comment: Are you using entityframework?

Comment: I personally like to have a repository each for comment and user and then on top of repositories I have my service classes, which give me the combined object from both these repositories. If you care using Entity framework, Include is also an option

Comment: Yes I'm (will clarify in question).

Comment: What object does your comment repository returns? Can you post your models that EF generated? If you properly connected Comments and Users you should have connection from comments to users and vice versa. I don't think that this is so complicated as you presented here.

Comment: Comment repository returns a 'Comment' object with following fields: [Id], [Content], [UserId], [CreationTime]. The [UserId] is linked to the user that created the comment.

Comment: So as mentioned in my question, the Comment model does contain a UserId but not an object.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any of the three options you mention. If you have a navigation property from Comment to User, you can handle that in your mapping. Something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Comment, CommentUserDto>().ForMember(dest => dest.UserName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.User.UserName));
```

If you don't have a navigation property, then after your initial mapping, loop through the list of dto objects and call the appropriate _userRepository method to get the user information and populate the appropriate members of the dto object that way.

**Edit**

After seeing your models, what I would do (assuming a navigation property is not an option) is something like this:

```
var comments = _commentRepository.GetAll();

var results = new List<CommentUserDto>();

foreach(Comment comment in comments)
{
   var user = _userRepository.Get(comment.userId);
   var commentUserDto = new CommentUserDto
   {
      Content = comment.Content,
      CreationTime = comment.CreationTime,
      PosterName = user.Name,
      PosterSurname = user.Surname
   }

   results.Add(commentUserDto);
}

return results;
```

Comment: Thanks, like I mentioned the Comment class does have a UserId property.  Trying your example right now.

Comment: In your example the mapping is done between the Comment (has userid property) and the CommentUserDto (only necessary fields for view). But what about the needed user information that should also be stored in CommentUserDto so that they are accessible by the view. The result should be a list with all comments and with every comment the matching user information.

Comment: We can't help your if you don't post your model classes. So, please, can you update your question with model classes for Comment, User, and CommentUserDto (it seams that I can't stress this enough)

Comment: @Sam That's why the mapping example only works IF your Comment object has a navigation property to User. If it doesn't (and you don't want to add one), then you'll need to go the other way and after you do the initial mapping, loop through the list of dto objects and call the _userRepository method to get the user's data you need.

Comment: @MattyM I have a navigation property (UserId) in my Comment model. But mapping Comment with CommentUserDto will not retrieve the needed user information stored in the user table (look edited question for models). Or am I understanding you wrong?

Comment: Add this to your Comment model: public virtual User User {get;set;} and add an attribute to it like this [ForeignKey("UserId")] to it.